# How to change the app logo from a visualforce page using controller?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I want to develop a visualforce page where I need to change the logo of an app so that when we select an app the app icon should be changed. I want this using using controller. Please help me providing code. Thank you.

Comment: First of all Welcome to SFSE. We are really happy to see you here however I am afraid for us to help you, we require something that you have started with. Please post what you have written so far and someone will definitely help you. What you are asking is possible by _Setup>Create>Apps_ in sales-force. You can select an image for an app and the app logo will change automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. But my requirement is I want to do it using aVF page. I mean I have a picklist of custom apps. When I select an app from that picklist and upload a new image for that app from VF page, the app logo need to be changed. I dont have code to share. So please provide me the code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AppMenuItem](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_appmenuitem.htm) just query this Object and update **LogoUrl** field . it will work for you.

**Update:**
Here is code sample for you

```
AppMenuItem ami = [Select Id,LogoUrl from  AppMenuItem where Id= 'PassYourVariableHere'];
```

i just checked it is a read only object so you can only query the record. you cannot update it from here.

Comment: Can you please provide me the code.... Actually I want to do it dynamically..